# foreman start failed ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puppet, foreman

I have ruby and rails installed in my machine ruby version ( 1.9.3 ) and rails ( 3.2.21 ). But still the start command fails

```
Command:
     sudo service foreman start

Error:
    /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'rails (= 3.2.21) ruby' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

[image]

Comment: do you have rails gem listed in your gemfile?

Comment: try this: https://rvm.io/integration/sudo

Comment: everything installed! Please see the attached screenshot